Can one child component update state of another child without using the parent component?
I'm new to using React and have built a simple Vite + React app. It has a search form where where users can search substance names, and see a history of previous searches which are held in Local Storage.
The App.jsx is very simple in that it renders 2 components like this:
return (
   <>
      <SubstanceForm onSubmit={addSubstance} />
      <PreviousSearches substances={substances} deleteSubstance={deleteSubstance} />
   </>
 )

I understand the basics of how to use props and have managed to do that as shown above.
The problem I'm facing is that I want the user to be able to click on a previous search from the <PreviousSearches> component, populate that value into a form field inside <SubstanceForm> and re-run my search.
I read React - Change state in child component from another child component but the accepted answer says

This application sounds like the perfect use case for "Lifting State Up", i.e. holding the main state in the parent component.

I've seen numerous examples of the above but was curious if it's possible to do without modifying the parent component, App.jsx, at all?
In SubstanceForm.jsx I have:
export function SubstanceForm({ onSubmit }) {
    const [newSubstance, setNewSubstance] = useState("")

    return (<>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text"
            value={newSubstance}
            onChange={e => setNewSubstance(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </>)
}

As you can see the value attribute of the search input is equal to newSubstance. It's possible to update the state within the same component with setNewSubstance.
I want to be able to do something like this in PreviousSearches.jsx:
<a href="#" onClick={() => setNewSubstance({searchCriteria}) }>{searchCriteria}</a>

In this case {searchCriteria} refers to a value (search keywords) of a previous search which is held in Local Storage. This is accessible inside PreviousSearches.jsx. However setNewSubstance is not accessible because it's in the other component (SubstanceForm.jsx).
Is there any way to call setNewSubstance from PreviousSearches.jsx?
The linked SO post seems to suggest modifying App.jsx and then handle all state through that. That seems quite convoluted especially as the app grows. Is there a way you can modify state in one child component from another without any reliance on changing the parent component?

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

This question is similar to: How to update the state of a sibling component from another sibling or imported component in REACT. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Phil not really the same because the question you've linked to was asked 6 years ago and doesn't seem to be how you would do this in React in 2024. That said I got the answer I needed and here - and it was helpful.

Who cares how old it is? The way React handles the flow of data is core to its design and has not changed.

You can indeed update the state right from within the child components, but you will need to pass a state variable declared on your parent component to it. Here's what you can do:
App.jsx
const [newSubstance, setNewSubstance = useState("")

return (
   <>
      <SubstanceForm newSubstance={newSubstance} setNewSubstance={setNewSubstance} />
      <PreviousSearches substances={substances} newSubstance={newSubstance} deleteSubstance={deleteSubstance} />
   </>
 )

SubstanceForm.jsx
export function SubstanceForm({ newSubstance, setNewSubstance }) {
    return (<>
        <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={newSubstance}
              onChange={e => setNewSubstance(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </>)
}

If you don't want to involve the parent component at all, then you'd need some global state management like Redux. In your example your parent component is already the App.jsx - basically the highest component, which is why I reckon to go with simply passing a parent-defined state variable and its setter function to the children.

In React, directly updating state in one child component from another without involving the parent is challenging due to the "one-way data flow" principle. This ensures data flows down from parent to child, making applications more predictable.
However, if you really want to avoid modifying App.jsx as a parent, you can go through few alternative approaches:
Context API: You can create a context to hold shared state (like newSubstance) and the setter function (setNewSubstance). Both SubstanceForm and PreviousSearches can then access and modify this shared state, bypassing the need to lift the state into App.jsx.
Custom Hook: Another way is to create a custom hook to manage the newSubstance state. This can be imported and used by both components without needing to modify App.jsx.

The functional components may be combined in different ways to get the desired functionality.
When we look at the components in the question at discrete units - not with respect to any kind of relationship, and list them, it is the following.
a) Root component
b) SubstanceForm
c) PreviousSearches

While listing the same from the point of a component hierarchy, it would be as below.
a) Root component
   b) SubstanceForm
   c) PreviousSearches

Since everything is a component it can combine in different ways.  It means, an alternate model is that the component PreviousSearches can contain the component SubstanceForm. In that case, we can say the component PreviousSearches is composed of the component SubstanceForm. The below tree shows the same.
a) Root component
   b) SubstanceForm
   c) PreviousSearches
      d) SubstanceForm

Now let us code for this model.
Coding highlights:
A new prop - searchString
/*
    a. A new props named searchString has been added to the component SubstanceForm.
    b. This new props will have a default value of empty string.
    c. When SubstanceForm is rendered from the root component, this props will be an empty string.
    d. However, while it is rendered from PreviousSearches, this new props will have the selected search string from the search history.
*/

Initial value for the state - newSubstance
/*
The initial value of the state newSubstance will be with respect 
to the new props - searchString.
*/

Controlling form submission
/*
The form submission will be controlled based on the new props in such a
way that, when the component is rendered for a new search,  the new 
search string will be added to the substances stage. If the component is 
rendered from PreviousSearches, then the form submission will just 
perform the search, still it will not be added to the state since it has 
already been added.
*/

Code full listing
App.js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [substances, setSubstances] = useState([]);

  function addSubstance(newSubstance) {
    setSubstances([...substances, newSubstance]);
  }

  function deleteSubstance(Substance) {
    // TO-DO
  }

  return (
    <>
      A New search
      <SubstanceForm
        onSubmit={addSubstance}
        substances={substances}
        deleteSubstance={deleteSubstance}
      />
      <PreviousSearches
        substances={substances}
        deleteSubstance={deleteSubstance}
      />
    </>
  );
}

function SubstanceForm({ onSubmit, searchString = '' }) {
  const [newSubstance, setNewSubstance] = useState(searchString);
  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          if (!searchString) {
            onSubmit(newSubstance);
            setNewSubstance('');
          } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(`search is done with the string ${searchString}`);
          }
        }}
        action="#"
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          value={newSubstance}
          name="searchstring"
          onChange={(e) => setNewSubstance(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

function PreviousSearches({ substances, deletesubstances }) {
  return (
    <>
      <br />
      The search history
      <br />
      {substances.map((searchString, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <SubstanceForm searchString={searchString} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

Test run
On adding the first search string

On adding the second search string

On selecting the first search string from the history

On selecting the second search string from the history

